# HTML Image not displaying, while the src url works

Tags: html, image

```
<img class="sealImage" alt="Image of Seal" src="file:///C:/Users/Anna/Pictures/Nikon%20Transfer/SEALS%20PROJECT/j3evn.jpg">
```

That doesn't display an image, just the alt.
But if I go to

```
file:///C:/Users/Anna/Pictures/Nikon%20Transfer/SEALS%20PROJECT/j3evn.jpg
```

in a browser, the image displays.

I'm hosting this on xampp, on a windows machine right now.

I've tried different browsers, and with and without %20 for space, but I know that with is the correct way.(It worked with both, actually)

And I know the images will only be visible on the machine that's hosting it, that's not a problem.

Comment: Make sure, as @William Yang posted, that your image is on the computer that is _hosting_ the website. Pop it into your www folder, and then link to like: "src='j3evn.jpg'" and then you will be good to go.

Comment: yeh, I have the same issue. Absolute link _http://localhost/path/image.jpg works just fine in browser, but doesn't work within src tag :|

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your file needs to be located inside your www directory. For example, if you're using wamp server on Windows, j3evn.jpg should be located,

```
C:/wamp/www/img/j3evn.jpg
```

and you can access it in html via

```
<img class="sealImage" alt="Image of Seal" src="../img/j3evn.jpg">
```

Look for the www, public_html, or html folder belonging to your web server. Place all your files and resources inside that folder.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So instead of moving the images, I just created a soft link. I assumed that as the browser could access it from outside the hosted directory, it would be fine.

Comment: @Scuzzball nope, you have to move them. All resources such as html, css, and javascript has to be located inside your xampp's www directory.

Comment: @Scuzzball Think of it as your xampp www folder is the folder you want to show the world, whereas all other folders on your server / computer are hidden from view. Things are done this way for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this, but this is a project that will never see open internet, and I just did it with PHP as that's what I know, and it getting done quickly was important. It really should have been done in something else.

Answer (score 7):

My images were not getting displayed even after putting them in the correct folder, problem was they did not have the right permission, I changed the permission to read write execute. I used chmod 777 image.png. All worked then, images were getting displayed. :)

Comment: That was the issue for me !Thanks i was driving me crazy !

Comment: This keeps happening to me since I'm working cross platform, deploying to a linux VM. I think I've come to this comment 3 times now.

Answer (score 5):

It wont work since you use URL link with "file://".
Instead you should match your directory to your HTML file, for example:

Lets say my file placed in:

```
C:/myuser/project/file.html
```

And my wanted image is in:

```
C:/myuser/project2/image.png
```

All I have to do is matching the directory this way:

```
<img src="../project2/image.png" />
```

Answer (score 3):

my problem was not including the ../ before the image name

```
background-image: url("../image.png");
```

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I had `/` in front of the path (assets is a dir), such as:

`<img src="assets/images/logo.png>"` is correct one, while

`<img src="/assets/images/logo.png>"` returns an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can try just putting the image in the source directory. You'd link it by replacing the file path with `src="../imagenamehere.fileextension` In your case, j3evn.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

change the name of the image folder to img and then use the  HTML code

Answer (score -1):

**The simple solution is:**

1.keep the image file and HTML file in the same folder.

2.code: `<img src="Desert.png">`// your image name.

3.keep the folder in D drive.

Keeping the folder on the desktop(which is c drive) you can face the issue of permission.

Answer (score -1):

Not a direct answer to this particular question. But in case, you are giving the image address correctly like this,and wondering why you don't see the image in the output,

```
<img src ="../../../public/image.jpg"/>
```

Directly give the image name like ,

```
<img src="image.jpg"/>
```

Or if you have a folder inside **public** , like say **icons** , give it like

```
<img src="/icons/logo.jpg"/>
```

This is because, React already expects you to have all your images inside **public** folder. So you don't need to explictly give it.

Answer (score -3):

In your angular.json folder structure should be like this

```
"assets": [             
  "src/assets",
  "src/favicon.ico"
],
```

not this

```
"assets": [     
  "src/favicon.ico",
  "src/assets",
],
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to associate with the original question, nor does it seem to answer it.