# Spring Boot - Image assets are not being loaded even if they are permitted on WebSecurityConfig file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have recently wanted to add some image on a page within my Spring Boot application, templated with Thymeleaf.

Even other assets (js, css) are being loaded and served successfully, images inside permitted img folder is not being served, a broken image is shown on the designated page.

This is where the image resides:

**src/main/resources/static/img/image.png**

Excerpt from WebSecurityConfig:

```
.antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**","/uploads/**","**/favicon.ico").permitAll()
```

from the HTML (tried 2 ways, one with Thymeleaf and one without using th prefix):

```
<img class="featurette-image pull-left" th:src="@{../static/img/image.png}" />

<img src="../static/img/image.png"/>
```

Please guide me on how to proceed?

*Ps: I am using Java DSL, instead xml based configuration.*

I've made the search and and seen a couple solutions did not fit my situation. (Checked answers on these before:

[Spring Security Thymleaf static resources don't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36809561/spring-security-thymleaf-static-resources-dont-load)

[when spring security enabled, resouces(css or js) can't be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25368535/when-spring-security-enabled-resoucescss-or-js-cant-be-loaded)

[HTML Image not displaying, while the src url works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413929/html-image-not-displaying-while-the-src-url-works)
)

Comment: Have you tried th:src="@{/img/image.png}" ?

Comment: Thank you!

Worked like charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need "static" in your reference to the image, because Spring Boot by default adds those paths to the classpath ([source](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)):

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

So your reference to the file should be directly:

```
th:src="@{/img/image.png}"
```