# Src in <img/> tag is failing to load image

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working with react and want to implement an image in the img html tag.

This is my project:
[image]

My code, which is in Testimonials.js looks like this:

```
<img  className="s-img-switch" src="images/hero.jpg" alt="" />
```

and it doesn't work. I also tried like this:

```
<img  className="s-img-switch" src="./images/hero.jpg" alt="" />
<img  className="s-img-switch" src="../components/images/hero.jpg" alt="" />
```

but it also doesn't work. But when I put an URL, for example like this:

```
<img  className="s-img-switch" src="https://media.moddb.com/images/members/5/4550/4549205/dog.jpg" alt="" />
```

it works.

Also, if I import the image in Testimonials.css like this:

```
background-image: url("./images/hero.jpg");
```

it also works. So that would mean that the image is ok.

This is what I see when I inspect the page, no matter what I do:
[image]

I can't seem to find an answer for this, so all help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Image not displaying, while the src url works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413929/html-image-not-displaying-while-the-src-url-works)

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:- By making a component of the image that looks neet and clean code too for this solution You have to import the image on top of your component code first like

```
import heroImg from "path_of_folder/imageName.jpg";
```

and now you can use the image by

```
<img src={heroImg} />
```

Solution 2:- Copy your images folder into public folder it also work.